# Can't pass data from view to controller and fill grid data at the same time

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, http-post, jquery-bootgrid

So I have an issue where I can do only one thing at a time: Pass data to the post method in the controller without filling the grid data **OR** fill grid data without being able to pass data to the post method in the controller.

How can I do both? Here's what I've tried:

I have the following in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Search(QueryFilter[] myFilters)
{
    return Json(await DataService.GetData(myFilters, 1, -1, null));
}
```

In the first case I can pass the values to the controller but the grid data is empty. This is my script section in the view for this case:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#searchform").submit(function (event) {    
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/Monitor/Search")';
            $("#grid-data").bootgrid("destroy");
            $("#preloader").show();
            event.preventDefault();

            var Filters = new Array();    
            $('[name="CheckBox"]:checked').each(function () {
                Filters.push(new QueryFilter($(this).val()));
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                traditional: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(Filters),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',    
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("Success");
                    $("#grid-data").bootgrid(result); // Does not work
                }
            })
        });
        $("#preloader").hide();
    });    
    function QueryFilter(value) {
        this.Value = value
    }
</script>
```

In the second case I can't pass the values to the controller but the grid data is successfully filled. This is my script section in the view for this case:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#searchform").submit(function (event) {
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/Monitor/Search")';
            $("#grid-data").bootgrid("destroy");
            $("#preloader").show();
            event.preventDefault();

            var Filters = new Array();
            $('[name="CheckBox"]:checked').each(function () {
                Filters.push(new QueryFilter($(this).val()));
            });

            $("#grid-data").bootgrid({
                ajax:true
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                traditional: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(Filters),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                formatters: {
                    "DateOnly": function (column, row) {
                        return HelperScript.displayJsonDate(row[column.id]);
                    }
                },
                responseHandler: function (response) {
                    $("#preloader").hide();
                    return response;
                },
                requestHandler: function (request) {
                    return request;
                },
            })
        });
    });
    function QueryFilter(value) {
        this.Value = value
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found a pretty simple solution to my problem after more searching through the web.

So instead of `data: JSON.stringify(Filters)`

I used:

```
post: function () {
        return {
            myFilters: Filters
        };
    },
```

And the final code looks like this:

```
$("#grid-data").bootgrid({            
    ajax: true,   
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    post: function () {
        return {
            myFilters: Filters
        };
    },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    rowCount: -1,
    multiSort: true,

    formatters: {
        "DateOnly": function (column, row) {
            return HelperScript.displayJsonDate(row[column.id]);
        }
    },
    responseHandler: function (response) {
        $("#preloader").hide();
        return response;
    },
    requestHandler: function (request) {
        return request;
    },
})
```